# Applying function whose parameters depend on values of a column

Tags: python, performance, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe containing a column `type` of categorical data, and I have a table (dictionary) of parameter values for each possible *type*, each entry of which looks like

```
type1: [x1,x2,x3]
```

I have working code looking like this:

```
def foo(df):
    [x1,x2,x3] = parameters[df.type]
    return (* formula depending on x1,x2,x3,df.A,df.B *)

df['new_variable'] = df.apply(lambda x: foo(x), axis = 1)
```

Iterating through the rows like this (`.apply(..., axis=1)`) is of course very slow, and I'd like an efficient solution, but I don't know how to do the table-lookup in a neat manner. For instance, I can't just do

```
df['new_variable'] = (* formula depending on parameters[df.type][0:3],df.A,df.B *)
```

as that throws a `TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed` (I'm naively trying to use a Series as a key, which doesn't work).

I suppose I could make new columns for the parameter values, but that seems inelegant somehow, and I'm sure there is a better way. What's the best way to do this?

EDIT: I just realised I can get a column with the lists of parameters via

```
df.type.map(parameters)
```

but I can't access the entries of those lists, as the usual index-conventions don't seem to work. E.g. `df.type.map(parameters).loc[:,2]` gives an `IndexingError: Too many indexers`; basically pandas gets confused when having too many dimensions without sticking it all in a MultiIndex. Is there a way to get around this?

EDIT2: a minimal example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['dog',4],['dog',6],['cat',1],['cat',4]],columns = ['type','A'])
parameters = {'dog': [1,2], 'cat': [3,-1]}

def foo(x):
    [a,b]=parameters[x.type]
    return a * x.A + b

df['new'] = df.apply(foo,axis=1)
```

produces the desired output

```
  type  A  new
0  dog  4    6
1  dog  6    8
2  cat  1    2
3  cat  4   11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a vectorised solution you should split your series of lists, which is what `df['type'].map(parameters)` gives, into separate columns. You can then leverage efficient NumPy operations:

```
params = pd.DataFrame(df['type'].map(parameters).values.tolist(),
                      columns=['a', 'b'])

df['new'] = params['a'] * df['A'] + params['b']
```

As you note, `pd.DataFrame.apply` is a thinly veiled, and generally inefficient, loop. It should be avoided wherever possible.

Comment: Perfect, this is just the sort of thing I was after!

Comment: Just a caveat for anyone who reads this later: you have to make sure the indices of your `df` and your `params` match up; `params` as constructed here will be indexed by row number, regardless of how `df` is indexed.